# How create HttpSession using old JSESSIONID?

Tags: java, session, tomcat

How can I recreate HttpSession (with cookie, on servlet filters) using JSESSIONID from still active session, passed in request?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Where would you be re-creating it from? You mean you have the session data stashed away somewhere? What's the scenario? Recovering from a crashed server?

Comment: First user logs into using standalone application, he got JSESSIONID. Using mobile browser he need to access the same app omitting login page. He should use recived JSESSIONID and the server must recrete his cookies. First I've tried standard tomcat ";jsessionid=ACD..." paremeter witout cookies, but it breaks down all ajax stuff.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is hijack the session.  As the name suggests this is a security hole in your application because a malicious user could use the same mechanism to impersonate a good user.

To hijack the session the second client (the mobile browser in your case) is going to have to know the session id, so avoiding the log-in isn't really getting you anything because you're just replacing it with entering the session id.

Answer (score 1):

This is in theory a terrible and error-prone solution. The real solution lies somewhere else. Store the data of interest in some datastore (SQL database?) which is associated with the logged-in user. This way you can just access the same data on every login, regardless of the client application and machine used.