# passing session to another web application

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat

let say in tomcat application server we deployed 2 web applications  , web application A, web application B.  How to pro-grammatically sync session from web application A to web application B . In other words, as long as user login to web application A, he is already login to web application B. As well when he log out.

Comment: Duplicate or very similar to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155427/how-create-httpsession-using-old-jsessionid/1157772#1157772

Comment: Similar, yes. Same question, no.

Comment: What about this one? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665941/any-way-to-share-session-state-between-different-applications-in-tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check [Sharing session data between contexts HOW-TO](http://www.fwd.at/tomcat/sharing-session-data-howto.html) to see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this about authenticating user only once with same username and password for multiple sites?

If so google Single Sign On. There are a number of frameworks out there for doing just that.

Comment: why not? your question describes something SSO would solve easily

Answer (score 0):

Use the [single sign on valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Single%20Sign%20On).